# ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token using express.js

Tags: node.js, express, csrf-token

Iv been trying to integrate using csrf and after following some guides maybe iv missed something but to me it looks ok (Maybe still iv missed something)

App.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const csrf = require('csurf');

require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '/.env')}); //load .env variables

const app = express();
const csrfProtection = csrf();

const tasks = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    session: 'mySessions'
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //EJS
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public'))); //static folder route
app.use(session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    tasks : tasks
})) // setting up a session
app.use(csrfProtection); //csrf middleware


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuth = req.session.isLoggedin; //True after logging in
    res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
    next();
})

// Routes
const userData = require('../routes/user.js');
const listRoute = require('../routes/list.js');
const adminData = require('../routes/admin.js');
const errorController = require('../../controllers/errorController');

//Middleares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) //Body-Parser
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/"))); //bootstrap
app.use(userData);
app.use(listRoute);
app.use(adminData);
app.use(errorController.error404); //404 page


// Wait for database to connect, logging an error if there is a problem
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Mongoose connect: Connected');
        app.listen(process.env.PORT);
        console.log('Listening to port 3000')
      })
      .catch();
```

And when Im trying to log in im redirecting and getting the message "ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token"

Here is User interaction file UserController.js :

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const path = require("path");
const PASSWORD_SECURITY_LEVEL = 10;

exports.getRegisterUser = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('inside registerUser in userContorller');
    res.render('../views/register', {
        pageTitle: 'Register'
    });
}

exports.getLoginUser = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('../views/login', {
        pageTitle: 'Login',
    })
};

//TODO:Check what went wrong when logging it just redirecting maybe something with the form action check!!!
exports.postLoginUser = (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    //check csrfToken valid TODO:not sure this is wokrking maybe try something else
    if(req.csrfToken() !== req.body._csrf){
        res.status(403).send('CSRF token validation failed');
        return;
    }

    User.findOne({username: username})
        .then((user) => {
            if(!user){
                //TODO: Show proper message
                console.log('User field is empty');
                res.redirect('/login');//User not found
            }
            //check if the password is correct
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
                .then(passwordMatch => {
                    if(passwordMatch){
                        req.session.isLoggedin = true; //setup a session
                        req.session.user = user //save the user found in foundOne at the first .then
                        console.log('Password matched saving session and redirecting...')
                        return req.session.save((err) => {
                            if(err){
                                console.log('req.session.save error: ',err);
                            }else{
                                res.redirect('/');
                            }
                        })
                    }else{
                        //TODO: Show proper message.
                        console.log('Password is not correct redirecting back to login page.')
                        res.redirect('/login');
                    }
                })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('findOne error is: ', err);
    })
}

exports.postUserRegister = (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.user;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({username: username})
        .then((userFound) => {
            if (userFound) { //new user tried to register with the same username WAS found.
                console.log('Username is already exists!');
                res.redirect('/register');
            } else{
                return bcrypt.hash(password, PASSWORD_SECURITY_LEVEL)
                    .then(hashedPassword => {
                    const newUser = new User({
                        username: username,
                        password: hashedPassword
                    });
                    newUser.save()
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log('New user saved succesfuly')
                            res.redirect('/login');
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log('postUserRegister err:', err);
                            res.redirect('/register')
                        })
                });
            }
        })

        .catch(err => console.log('postUserRegister error: ', err)); //ADDED NEW LINE MIGHT CAUSE PROBLEM IN REGISTER PAGE
}

exports.postUserLogOut = (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
}
```

And the login.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Colorlib Templates">
    <meta name="author" content="Colorlib">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Colorlib Templates">

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title><%= pageTitle %></title>

    <!-- Icons font CSS-->
    <link href="/vendor/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- Font special for pages-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Vendor CSS-->
    <link href="/vendor/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/vendor/datepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- Register CSS-->
    <link href="/css/register.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>

<body>
<div class="page-wrapper bg-gra-02 p-t-130 p-b-100 font-poppins">
    <div class="wrapper wrapper--w680">
        <div class="card card-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="title">Log in</h2>
                <form action="/login-user" method="post">
                    <!--Username -->
                    <div class="row row-space">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label class="label">Username</label>
                                <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Password -->
                    <div class="row row-space">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label class="label">Password</label>
                                <input class="input--style-4" type="password" name="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Login button press-->
                    <form action="/login-user" method="post">
                        <div class="p-t-15">
                            <div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
                                <button class="login-btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue" type="submit">Log in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </form>

                <!--Register Button redirect -->
                <div class="p-t-15">
                    <label class="not-registered-label">Don't have a user?</label>
                    <div>
                        <a class="login-btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue" href="./register">Register Now!</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
<!-- end document-->
```

Thank you for helping any help will be aprriecited (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that your `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">` contains an empty value because from what I can see you never send the `csrfToken` along with your views. Try adding it as property of the optional second parameter object to the `res.render` method on all the views you know you will need it i.e. for form submissions like so:

```js
res.render('../views/register', {
   pageTitle: 'Register',
   csrfToken: req.csrfToken() //< Add this
});

//..

res.render('../views/login', {
   pageTitle: 'Login',
   csrfToken: req.csrfToken() //< Add this
})
```

You also seem to have a `<form>` within a `<form>` that may be causing you some issues. This form is contained within the outer form. Nested forms goes against HTML spec:

```
<form action="/login-user" method="post">
   <div class="p-t-15">
      <div>
         <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
         <button class="login-btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue" type="submit">Log in</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, Iv added the csrfToken to the view , and removed the nested <form> 
But still get the same error message , there is a way to compare the csrfToken im trying to compare to and the one im getting ?

Comment: Did you remember to add `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">` into the outer form as you had it in the inner form? Can you open up dev tools in your browser and make sure there is a value in there.

Comment: So what iv tried right now is to check if the token is been passed and from what i can see under the login button in the login page i can see inside the input the token (its not empty) maybe im generating a second token somewhere and when its trying to compare its getting the wrong result

Comment: Are you using JavaScript to submit the form (Axios/fetch) or is it a normal form submit?

Comment: Just normal form submit

Comment: How it works you send `csrfToken: req.csrfToken()` to your view. You then add the `value="<%= csrfToken %>">` hidden input and post the form. The `app.use(csrfProtection);` then checks the `_csrf` value against the visitor's session. The only thing I can see in your code is that you need to move `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) //Body-Parser` above the session and csurf middleware in your app.js file.

Comment: yess!! worked i moved the bodyParser above the csurf middleware .
Can you please explain to me the logic why it worked ?

Comment: Brilliant. Glad it worked. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @Nansi if you found the answer helfpul please consider [marking as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.).